# wp_get_current_user when not in root wp folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've the following directory setup

```
/sitename
   wp-content/
   wp/
   .htaccess
   wp-config.php
   index.php
```

In my theme functions.php I've the following test code

```
add_action('init', function () {
    var_dump( is_user_logged_in() );
});
```

My .htaccess is created by wordpress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Logged in backend as administrator, If I access `http://localhost/` the test code outputs `false`. Instead, if I access `http://localhost/wp/` the test code outputs `true`. Why is this happening?

Comment: and what is wp/ here, is this another setup of wordpress?

Comment: wp/ is the main wordpress install. wp-content/ is a custom content directory

Comment: It's because of the cookie path being set to `"/wp"` and thus not being accessible from `"/"`.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu! You were right, it was due to the cookie path.